# Collaboration platform with powerful search -> auto-building knowledge base

Tags: collaboration, search, wiki, knowledge-base

I'm looking for a collaboration platform similar to Asana, Trello, Podio or Wrike that has a powerful search engine with support for:

- Stemming: searching for "load" will find "loading", "loads" etc.
- Multi-word searches: searching for "stemming find" in the paragraph above should find it
- Highlight results wherever they occur, in context. So far, only Slack does this:

[image: Slack search highlights results]

What I've evaluated to far:

- Asana doesn't do any of the above.
- Trello does stemming and multi-word, but no highlighting.
- Wrike ORs all the terms, so searching for "foo bar" will find items that contain only "foo" and not "bar" (there's no `+` among the [operators Wrike provides](https://www.wrike.com/help/search/)).
- Podio only highlights the terms if they occur in succession and are not in a comment
- daPulse doesn't do stemming and search isn't a core feature despite the [Features page](https://dapulse.com/features) claiming "automatic knowledge base" (their Support told me "the search is mainly for people, posts, and boards")
- [Rocket.Chat](https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat#features) does stemming and multi-word, but no highlight.
- plus [50+ other tools](http://wiki.dandascalescu.com/reviews/online_services/customer_and_project_management_systems), but that was two years ago, so maybe some have made great strides in their full-text search capabilities...

Comment: Apart from the search, which basic/other features do you need? -- Hosted and/or self-hosted?

Comment: @unor: if I could even find *any* software with decent search! Both types of hosting are fine. It's amazing how lousy the search is, when there are excellent search-as-a-service providers like Algolia out there, and given how crowded the collaboration tools market is.

Comment: I see, but you should still explicitly state in your question what kind of tool you need. "collaboration platform" is pretty broad, and while listing tools that are no matches is helpful, it’s not sufficient: not everyone knows these tools, but might have a recommendation for you; and it’s likely that you don’t need *all* other features these mentioned tools offer (see: [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/60)). As you have used the [tag:wiki] tag, would a typical wiki (with such a search feature) be a possible solution?

Comment: @unor: a Mediawiki-like wiki would be too arcane to use (the commenting system is a hack). A wiki with sane commenting would be something I'd consider.